# Me![SubForm1].Form.RecordsetClone is prompting for datasource selection

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2016 with VBA and ADO.

I have a parent form "ABC" and it is having a subform "SubForm1". For Subform1, i have set the SourceObject through VBA code like below. Data is displaying in SubForm1, all good so far.

`Me.[SubForm1].SourceObject = "XYZ"`

XYZ form recorset assigned as below

```
In form_open

Dim rsF As ADODB.Recordset
get_rsData rsF , 10,20,30
Set Me.Recordset = rsF 
rsF .Close
Set rsF = Nothing
---------------
Function get_rsData (rs As ADODB.Recordset, x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer) As ADODB.Recordset

OpenMyRecordset rs, "sp_F " & x & ", " & y & ", " & z, rrOpenDynamic, rrLockOptimistic, False
End Function
----------
Public Function OpenMyRecordset(rs As ADODB.Recordset, strSQL As String, Optional rrCursor As rrCursorType, Optional rrLock As rrLockType, Optional bolClientSide As Boolean) As ADODB.Recordset
Debug.Print strSQL
On Error GoTo ConnectionError
    If con.State = adStateClosed Then
        con.ConnectionString = conConnection
        con.Open
    End If

On Error GoTo RecordsetError
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CursorType = IIf((rrCursor = 0), adOpenStatic, rrCursor)
        .LockType = IIf((rrLock = 0), adLockReadOnly, rrLock)
        .Open strSQL
        If .EOF And .BOF Then
            NoRecords = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With

ExitProcedure:
    Exit Function
    
    
RecordsetError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Function
    
    
ConnectionError:
    MsgBox "No connection to server"
    
    
    
End Function
```

Now, When I try to get recordsetclone, it is not working and it is prompting for a data source

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = Me![SubForm1].Form.RecordsetClone
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Recordset seems to be closed, and returning an error like operation is not allowed when object is closed

Comment: I get "Typt mismatch" error on the Set line. I can get it to work only with `Dim rst As DAO.Recordset`. AFAIK, RecordsetClone is DAO feature.

Comment: Also, the `Set =` method you show is DAO syntax for opening recordset.

Comment: @June7, i have tried with DAO.Recordset and it was throwing a message like operation not allowed when object is closed. Subform.Form.RecordsetClone is promoting for data source.

Comment: Again, DAO works for me, even with setting SourceObject property. Cannot replicate issue. Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

Comment: @June, i am trying to get ADODB record set similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordsetclone, for DAO, there is a different feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/create-a-dao-recordset-from-a-form

Comment: That first link does not specify recordset type but it uses DAO syntax so it is not an ADODB example. In fact, it fails in my test until I declare DAO.Recordset. Can't use DAO syntax to get ADODB recordset. ADODB syntax uses Open method. AFAIK, ADODB recordset cannot be set to RecordsetClone. Why do you need ADODB?

Comment: @June, I was using ADODB to retrieve the data from database and assigned ADODB recordset to subform. With DAO recordset, Me![SubForm1].Form.RecordsetClone is working fine. Thank you for the help. It will be great if you can provide any inputs on how to clone ADODB recordset that is assigned to a Subform. Thankyou

Comment: And exactly how are you assigning subform with ADODB recordset? Edit your question.

Comment: Well, it really doesn't seem to matter how form data is set. Code works when use `Dim rst As DAO.Recordset`. RecordsetClone is a DAO feature. But where are you pulling data from that you need this? Why not just set RecordSource property with SQL string?